# Accessing Widget State instances in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble accessing instances of objects (or States) in Flutter, from other classes. I've tried a lot of fiddling using similar questions on the web, and am currently using 'GlobalKey', but I just can't get it working.

I'm trying to make a simple Flutter app where the State of a Widget gets accessed from another class, on button press:

```
import 'viewer.dart' as viewer;
(...)
onPressed: () {
    //Works
    print("Doing something");
    
    //Doesn't work
    viewer.key.currentState.nextPage();
},
```

My viewer.dart file looks contains a PageController, and a class containing that controller:

```
final key = new GlobalKey<_RegistryState>();

final PageController _controller = PageController(
  initialPage: 0,
);


class Registry extends StatefulWidget {
  Registry({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegistryState createState() => _RegistryState();
}

class _RegistryState extends State<Registry> {
  void next() {
    print("Doing something!");
    _controller.nextPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Disable user manually scrolling
      controller: _controller,
      children: [
        registry_screens.ScreenSplash(),
        registry_screens.ScreenName(),
        Text("Bye"),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The idea is that whenever the button gets pressed, the PageController moves to the next page (which is already there, I can scroll to it manually by swiping on the screen).

The app compiles fine, but when pressing the button I get the error 'NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'next''.

Am I using the correct approach for accessing instances of Widgets (or States)?

Comment: Your question leads me to believe you have a core misunderstanding of state. A widget should never "directly access" another widget's state. Instead, we leave it up to a widget to provide functions to those below it that tell them how to modify the parent's state.

Basically I recommend reading [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up) very closely

Comment: @DrSatan1 It seems you are right, I will take a better look at the fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is a declarative framework. In this kind of environment, everytime that you want to change the view (or interface) you need to rebuild it. And if you rebuild what is holding the state, you would loose it. That's why it should not be responsible of holding the state of the program.

State management in Flutter is a broad subject with lots of options. As @DrSatan1 mentioned in the comments, in [Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up) you can find good documentation about state management using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), but you have lots of options with [BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), [ReduX](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux), [MobX](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx), etc.

In your specific scenario, since it is simpler, you could accomplish that using a global object or `Inherited Widget`.

***Global Object***

globals.dart

```
currentPage=0;
```

In the Widget

```
import 'globals.dart' as global;
(...)
onPressed: () {
    setState((){
        globals.currentPage++;
    });
},
```

viewer.dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Disable user manually scrolling
      currentPage: globals.currentPage, //instead of using PageController
      children: [
        registry_screens.ScreenSplash(),
        registry_screens.ScreenName(),
        Text("Bye"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

You could use the `PageController` as your global object. In that case you could pass the PageController down the widget tree. In this case, it would be better to use `InheritedWidget` instead.

***InheritedWidget***

As per [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), `InheritedWidget` is

> Base class for widgets that efficiently propagate information down the
> tree.

You can pass your PageController to all the widgets below the tree. Your viewer.dart would be:

```
(...)
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyInheritedWidget (
      pageController: _controller,
      child: PageView(
        //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Disable user manually scrolling
        //controller: _controller, // Don't pass controller here
        children: [
          registry_screens.ScreenSplash(),
          registry_screens.ScreenName(),
          Text("Bye"),
        ],
      );
    );
    
}

(...)
// create the inherited widget wrapper. It could be done with [Builder][7] too, instead of a different Widget.

class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  MyInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.pageController,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
}
(...)
```

After that you can access pageController in PageView or any Widget under it.

```
(...)
onPressed: () {
    //Works
    print("Doing something");
    
    // Find closest InheritedWidget
    MyInheritedWidget myInheritedWidget = 
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>()
    // Get pageController from it
    PageController controller = myInheritedWidget.pageController
    // call nextPage()
    nextPage();
},
(...)
```

Although both methods works in your specific scenario, you should check Flutter Docs about state management. Maybe you don't need the PageController at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea for state to be accessed externally. Instead, external classes should only interact with Widgets through the methods they expose.

I just made a video walking through the exact same onboarding setup you have using a `PageView`, which you can see here -- as I go through it step-by-step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji__FEKSnMw

In essence, it looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MainPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  PageController pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
            child: PageView(
                controller: pageController,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
              Slide(
                  hero: Image.asset("./assets/hero-1.png"),
                  title: "Boost your traffic",
                  subtitle:
                      "Outreach to many social networks to improve your statistics",
                  onNext: nextPage),
              Slide(
                  hero: Image.asset("./assets/hero-2.png"),
                  title: "Give the best solution",
                  subtitle:
                      "We will give best solution for your business isues",
                  onNext: nextPage),
              Slide(
                  hero: Image.asset("./assets/hero-3.png"),
                  title: "Reach the target",
                  subtitle:
                      "With our help, it will be easier to achieve your goals",
                  onNext: nextPage),
              Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Be kind to yourself',
                    style: kTitleStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextPage() {
    pageController.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease);
  }
}

class Slide extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget hero;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final VoidCallback onNext;

  const Slide({Key key, this.hero, this.title, this.subtitle, this.onNext})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: hero),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: kTitleStyle,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  subtitle,
                  style: kSubtitleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 35,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: onNext,
            child: Text(
              "Skip",
              style: kSubtitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```